# Update array in mongodDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, curl, express

Building an API with node/express. I'm having problem updating an array inside a collection with mongoDB. I just want to add a reference id to the useritems array in the collection user.

User looks like this:

```
[
    {
        fbname: "name.name",
        email: "name.name@hotmail.com",
        username: "mr.name",
        useritems: [ObjectId("51e101df2914931e7f000003"), ObjectId("51e101df2914931e7f000005"), ObjectId("51cd42ba9007d30000000001")]
    }];
```

In my server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    item = require('./routes/items');

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));    
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.put('/users/:userId/item/:itemId/add', item.addUserItem);
```

query:

```
exports.addUserItem = function(req, res) {
    var user = req.params.userId; 
    var item = req.params.itemId; 
    console.log('Updating useritem for user: ' + user);
    console.log("item: ", item);

    db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {

        collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(user)}, {$addToSet: { useritems: item}}); 

    });
}
```

When i try it with curl nothing happens and i get the error: (52) Empty reply from server, from curl

Curl:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: applicatio/json' http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/51e6a1116074a10c9c000007/item/51e6a1116074a10c9c000006/add
```

Comment: But does it update the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(user)}, {$addToSet: { useritems: item}}, true, function(err, result){
    res.json(200, result);
});
```

Comment: @Bullfinch, did it work exactly as expected, coz I didn't test it, I just posted it?

Comment: Thank you! Works! Now im trying to delete the item: 
`collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(user)}, {$pull: { useritems: item}}, true, function(err, result){
            res.json(200, result);
        });` But curl gives me 404 on that, the id exist in the useritems array. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Bullfinch, you can't delete with `update`, you need `remove`

Comment: Yea, but i dont think you can use remove on an item in an array, only when i want the whole user to be removed from the collection i use reomve. Here i basically want to update the useritems array so i thought i could use update and the `$pull`function. But i cant get it to work properly

Comment: `collection.update({ useritems: item}, {$pull: { useritems: item}}, true, function(err, result){ res.json(200, result); });` Try that.